# How can I recover encrypted files after system reinstallation

Tags: encryption, operating-systems

I had a file which contains images and videos, I was using the windows 7 ultimate and I had encrypted the file. Now I have copied that file to my hard disk and format that operating system and again. I installed a fresh copy of operating system windows7 ultimate, now when I want to see my file which I had saved in hard disk, file is not opening and generate some permission issues.

How can I recover my data?

Comment: Can you confirm that: 1. The file was encrypted using Windows 7 Encrypting File System (EFS) by right-clicking on a file, choosing Advanced and selecting "Encrypt contents to secure data". 2. Do you have a backup of the computer before you reinstalled Windows? 3. Where did you copy the file when you reinstalled Windows?

Comment: Pls add specifics on how files were encrypted (missing at time of posting this comment).

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a copy of the key?

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Recover-encrypted-files-or-folders

Connect the drive that contains the encrypted file.
Connect the drive that contains the backed-up certificate and key.
Start certmgr.msc
Import the certificate

You should now have access to the files.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457020.aspx

Answer (score -4):

you can never open the encrypted files if you don't have the certification keys for the OS where you encrypt this file.

Comment: Do you mean the "encryption keys" and not "certification keys"? I'm not sure what a "certification key" is.